# C++20 Formatter Template Redefinition Error

Tags: c++, c++20

**What I am trying to do:** define two `fmt::formatter` templates, one for types that derive from `std::exception` and one for types that derive from `std::array<char, N>` so that I can pass these types as parameters to a logging function that uses `fmt::format()`.

**Problem:** when I define only one of the formatter templates, everything works as expected, but when I define both, I get an error that states that I am redefining a type:

```
error: redefinition of ‘struct fmt::v7::formatter<T, char, void>’
```

**Code sample:**

```
template<typename T>
concept Exception = std::is_base_of_v<std::exception, T>;

template<std::size_t arrayLen>
template<typename T>
concept CharArray = std::is_base_of_v<std::array<char, arrayLen>, T>;

template <Exception T>
struct fmt::formatter<T> {

    constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context& ctx) {
        return ctx.begin();
    }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const T& ex, FormatContext& ctx) {
        return format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", ex.what());
    }
};

template <CharArray T>
struct fmt::formatter<T> {

    constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context& ctx) {
        return ctx.begin();
    }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const T& arr, FormatContext& ctx) {
        const std::string str{arr.data(), strnlen(arr.data(), arr.size())};
        return format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", str);
    }
};
```

**Dev environment:** g++ 11.1.0, CentOS, `fmt` from `<spdlog/fmt/bundled/format.h>`

**What I have tried:** I tried defining the two concepts Exception and CharArray such that they are mutually exclusive. I have tried using a concept other than CharArray which is not templated on a size argument. I tested that having two `void foo(T)` functions, one templated on `Exception` and one on `CharArray` works as expected.

**What I am looking for:** At this point, I'm far more interested in an explanation about what I am doing incorrectly than I am in potential work-arounds. I have several work-arounds in mind if it comes to that, but I really want to figure out where my misunderstanding is so I can learn from it.

Thanks in advance for your help and please be kind in your responses.

**Solution update:** I was defining the `CharArray` concept incorrectly and it wasn't being caught by GCC. I also needed to move my templates inside the `fmt` namespace due to a GCC bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```cpp
template<std::size_t arrayLen>
template<typename T>
concept CharArray = std::is_base_of_v<std::array<char, arrayLen>, T>;
```

is not a valid declaration. I'm surprised the compiler does not flag that as being obviously ill-formed (reported as [102289](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102289)).

You only get one template head for a `concept` (the only place you can write multiple such `template` declarations is when you're defining member function templates of class templates outside of the class body, or other things like that).

The way you can write this concept in C++20 is:

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
void f(std::array<char, N> const&);

template <typename T>
concept CharArray = requires (T t) { f(t); }
```

Basically, if you can call `f(t)` with a `T`, then that means that `t` either is some kind of `std::array<char, N>` or inherits from one. With additional lambda features in C++20, we can even put that into the concept itself:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept CharArray = requires (T t) {
    []<std::size_t N>(std::array<char, N> const&){}(t);
};
```

The lambda here just exists to do that same "is callable" check that we did with the free function template.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point and great explanation (and thanks for reporting the gcc issue)! Unfortunately, this did not solve my problem; I am still getting the same redefinition error. Any thoughts on how I can resolve this?

Comment: @JimPri That's another gcc bug (preexisting [92944](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92944)). For now, put your specializations entirely in `namespace fmt`

Comment: Thank you! In the highly unlikely possibility that our paths ever cross in real life, I totally owe you a drink.

Comment: @Barry I must have seriously annoyed the compiler gods today; your concept definition with the lambda causes Clang to crash. :)